# TestNG Cannot find class in classpath

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, classpath

I am getting `Cannot find class in classpath: testng.unitTest` error. I have seen many posts on this issue and tried all the possible ways, but nothing worked. TestNG is working fine on Eclipse. **When I run it from command line, it is throwing error**. I did setup classpath correctly, have all the jar files in lib folder. Testng.xml file is located in project directory. What could be the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Sample test Suite">
   <test name="Sample test">
    <classes>
      <class name="testng.unitTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

execution from command line

```
C:\workspace\selenium> java -cp "C:/workspace/selenium/lib/testng.jar;C:/workspace/selenium/lib/jcommander.jar" org.testng.TestNG testNG.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add project compiled code to the Java classpath i.e. path to the bin follder.

Try this:

```
C:\workspace\selenium>java -cp "C:/workspace/selenium/lib/testng.jar;C:/workspace/selenium/lib/jcommander.jar;C:/workspace/selenium/your_bin_folder" org.testng.TestNG testNG.xml
```

Comment: @Ela hope this helps!